# What is missing from my coding to for both google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a google spreadsheet with two sheets on it. I am getting notifications for all of my functions except function notifyIT(). I feel like I need to address the tabs. The tabs on the spreadsheet are called 'Termed' and 'New Hires'.

The only email that I am not getting is for the function notifyIT() which is for our termed people. The email that I used to receive read "Terminated "location" Employee "Employee Name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code:

```
objects = getRowsData(dataSheet, dataRange);
```

Is calling a function that you haven't shown.  Without that, we can't evaluate your code.

Comment: I have added all the code for you! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The tabs are referred to as Sheets, which reside within a parent Spreadsheet. So instead of

```
var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
```

which is returning the first Sheet in your Spreadsheet, if you want to get  specific sheet, you can use getSheetByName:

```
var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('New Hires');
```

See docs here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)

Another option is to use getSheets(), but loop over the result:

```
var dataSheets = ss.getSheets();
for(var i in dataSheets){
    var dataSheet = dataSheets[i];

    //continue your code here.
}
```

Comment: I have added my whole code if you want to look again. I did what you suggested and no luck. Thank you for helping!